# Loop Transforms to Increase Parallelism

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing, loops

I have the need to parallelize as much as I can (in order to make it run fast) the following part of an algorithm:

```
do i=1, n
  do j=1, n
    A[i, j] = A[i-4, j-4] + A[i-3, j-3] + B[i, j]
  end do
end do
```

I was thinking that the best i could do here is a loop skewing (but with what factor?) and loop interchange that would allow me to finally have a DOALL on the inner loop. Any feedack and help regarding those thoughts?

Comment: The diagonals are indepedendent, so you can compute those in parallel. Note that this will be memory-bound, so you can only expect a speedup of you store `A` and `B` by diagonals from the start. This will give you a speedup if you stay sequential, too, since it uses the cache more effectively.

Comment: @Raphael Why not increase parallelism even more by computing (within each diagonal as you mentioned) every two sequentially and those tuples on parallel ? (something like loop unrolling)

Comment: Try it out and benchmark it. My feeling is that unless it reduces the number of cache misses, it won't do much for you. Also, keep cache syncing in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar in principle to an h.264 decoder where each cell depends on the cell above and the cell to the left.

Let k = i + j. Then some A with i + j = k only depends on A with i + j = k-8 and i + j = k-6. Assuming your indices start at 1, you need to define the result for i <= 4, j <= 4 first.

Loop for k = 2 to 2n. For each k, loop for i, and let j = k - n; you restrict the range for the i's is so that 1 ≤ j ≤ n. Then all the results for k to k+5 can be calculated in parallel.

```
do k = 2 to 2n
    do i = max (1, k - n) to min (n, k-1)
        A[i, k - i] = A[i-4, k - i - 4] + A[i-3, k - i - 3] + B[i, k - i]
    end do
end do
```

The inner loop can be executed fully in parallel because setting A[i, j] only affects results for k+6. Just make sure the calculation is finished before you start the loop for k + 6. It should also be reasonably cache friendly. And make sure you handle i, j ≤ 4 correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incomplete question because you have no base case; `A[-3, -3]` is not defined, for example. But let's assume we're looking at a window into a larger array, so those values have some consistent, distinct and independent value.

Denote those predetermined values with `#`, and look at the top-left corner. The values we can fill in are those three topmost rows and three leftmost columns, denoted by `·`.

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # · · · · · · · · · ·
# # # # · · · · · · · · · ·
# # # # · · · · · · · · · ·
# # # # · · ·
# # # # · · ·
# # # # · · ·
# # # # · · ·
# # # # · · ·
# # # # · · ·
# # # # · · ·
```

Doing those in parallel means that you need to take `n / 3` sequential steps. Since the matrix is square, exclusively going down balances the costs better, but still gives you `n / 3` sequential steps with parallelism of `3n`.

This is remarkably excessive for a typical CPU for significantly sized `n`; rather you should be streaming memory into SIMD operations as fast as possible. You can do a straightforward `N`-wide SIMD loop over the x-axis.

```
A[i:i+N, j] = A[i-4:i-4+N, j-4] + A[i-3:i-3+N, j-3] + B[i:i+N, j]
```

This probably won't max out your bandwidth entirely, but it will get pretty darn close and it's unlikely you can get more from a multicore algorithm, though you are free to try partitioning the work along diagonals.